# failed to pass file from ajax to php

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can i pass file from ajax to php without form??

when i try i failed to pass file from ajax to php

this is my input code :

```
<input id="ProdukPhoto_sample" data-insert="ProdukPhoto" class="filestyle" type="file" data-buttontext="Upload" data-buttonname="btn btn-sm btn-upload pointer" style="position: absolute; clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);" tabindex="-1">
```

this is my js :

```
var UploadImg = document.getElementById(id)
if (UploadImg.addEventListener) {
    UploadImg.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        handleFile(e, this);
    }, false);
}
```

function : handlefile

```
function handleFile(e, element) {
    var files = e.target.files;
    var i, f;
    console.log(files)

    for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
        var name = f.name;
        var ext = name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        var isiimage = 0;
        if (ext != 'jpeg' && ext != 'jpg' && ext != 'png') {
            alert('File yang di upload tidak support, silakan upload yang support : jpg, jpeg, png');
            return;
        }else{
            console.log(f)
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "proses.php",
                data: 'param='+f,
                error: function (msg) {
                    return ;
                },
            });

        }
    }
}
```

the result from console.log(f)

```
 File { name="previous1.png", lastModified=1421541967341, lastModifiedDate=Date, more...}
```

i try to catch the post data using php :

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, true) . '</pre>';

// result no received anything

<pre>Array
(
)
</pre>
```

can someone help me, what should i do to pass file from ajax to php
thanks

Comment: what does your `param` var stands for?

Comment: It was the first result on google: http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: @FabioG : that is mistake when i type, i have edit my script

Comment: This will never work with `'param='+f`. You're casting the file object to a string. Have you tried with  `data: { param: f }` ?

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll : how to read data [object filelist] in php?? when i try the solution inside and when i var_dump($_POST['file']);  i got [object filelist]

Comment: @Juhana : i got error when i {param : f}

Comment: Ok, what did the error message say?

Comment: The files should be in the $_FILES array!

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll : when i use var_dump($_FILES); the result i got is : array(0) {
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: [abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax)

The files will be available in the `$_FILES` php array.